# MathJax - Optimize performance on multiple typeset

Tags: markdown, mathjax, wmd, wmd-editor, pagedown

I'm trying to implement partial rendering in [my Markdown editor](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit) by converting Markdown/Tex in modified paragraphs only.
So basically, I have a `#preview` element that contains multiple `.preview_section` elements containing themselves the converted HTML paragraphs. When I update one or more `.preview_section` element, I'd like MathJax to process only those elements.

I tried different approaches:

- Pass the list of modified `.preview_section` elements as typset parameter. That's the worst solution in term of performance. When passing more than 1 element, the time to render is almost multiplied by the number of elements.
- Pass the `#preview` element as typeset parameter. The problem with this solution is that MathJax renders again the already rendered `script[type="math/tex; mode=display"]`. I tried to set the tex2jax `ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore"` configuration and to add `.tex2jax_ignore` to both unmodified `.preview_section` elements and already rendered `script` elements but it has no effect as it's not processed by tex2jax preprocessor (I suppose).
- Pass the `#preview` element as typeset parameter but after removing all the `script[type="math/tex; mode=display"]` from the preview. That's the most efficient, but I don't really like to remove these scripts from the preview.

Is there any ways to tell MathJax not to processing those `script` elements? Or any ideas before I plunge myself into the source code... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found my problem. MathJax stores a JavaScript object in every `script[type="math/tex"]` element in the DOM. This object, actually stored in `element.MathJax`, contains :

```
checked: 1
elementJax: Object
preview: span.MathJax_Preview
startNumber: 0
state: 2
```

where `state` is the state of the preview (2 means PROCESSED). So the TypeSet does not render the preview again if it has already been rendered, unless you rewrite the script tag in the DOM (that's what I was doing), this case you lose the MathJax object and the state of the preview. That's why MathJax was keeping re-rendering all my scripts.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I can only use some external javascript files for mathjax, and it's very hard to tweak the preview. I'm using chatjax code. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zky72/71/ Do you know if is it possible to use chatjax so that the preview is nicely ?

Comment: you could just call `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, element]);` for each element that needs to be updated...?

Comment: That's the first approach but it's rather very slow.